# Why does GDM start in TTY2 and TTY7

Tags: gdm, tty, ubuntu-gnome, 15.04

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and GNOME 3.16 installed.

This PPAs are enabled:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu vivid main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu vivid main
```

Interestingly, GDM runs in TTY1 and TTY7. Is there a way to fix this? I would like that GDM runs only in TTY7.

Comment: @Rinzwind `FirstVT=7` in `/etc/gdm/gdm.conf` works. Make an answer here and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198293/107084). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `/etc/gdm/gdm.conf` you can set what the 1st terminal should be the graphical interface. `FirstVT=7` will make GDM check tty7 first (by the way: this could mean it ends up on tty8, tty9 if these are enabled and tty7 is not free.

If this is inactive in `/etc/gdm/gdm.conf` it will probably randomly start with tty1 and if that is active (ie. a terminal session is open) it will pick tty2 and so on.